# Giving Error----java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

After  adding the MapOverlay class inside MapsActivity my  app is crashing at the starting time.I added Mapoverlay class & onTouchevent to get lat & lon when i touch on the map.without Mapoverlay class it's working but I need to get lat & long by touching on map.So what is the solurion.Help me pla....
  **MapsActivity.java**

```
package com.mamun.tasktest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MapsActivity<GeoPoint, OverlayItem> extends MapActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private LocationManager manager;

    private TextView tvAddress;
    private Button btnSearch;
    private EditText etSearch;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    public Bundle mapOverlays;
    MapView mapView;
    GeoPoint p;

     class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
        {
           @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e,
                com.google.android.maps.MapView mapView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               if(e.getAction()==1){
                   com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                          p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," +
                          p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ,
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            return false;
        }
        } 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        tvAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvaddress);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.maps);
        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    }

    public void onSearch(View v) {

        // Getting user input location
        String location = etSearch.getText().toString();

        if (location != null && !location.equals("")) {
            new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        locationClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        try {

            Location currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();
            double lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            double lng = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            // txtLocation.setText(lat + ", " + lng);

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

            ArrayList<Address> address = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder
                    .getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                            currentLocation.getLongitude(), 5);
            Address addr = address.get(0);
            String currentAddress = (addr.getAddressLine(0) + "-"
                    + addr.getAdminArea() + "-" + addr.getLocality() + "-"
                    + addr.getPostalCode() + "-" + addr.getCountryCode());
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            options.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            options.title(currentAddress);
            options.snippet("Current location");
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            if (googleMap != null) {
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(lat, lng), 14.0f));
                googleMap.addMarker(options);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map is null",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
    private class GeocoderTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Address>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            ArrayList<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder.getFromLocationName(
                        locationName[0], 3);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addresses;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Address> addresses) {

            if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Clears all the existing markers on the map
            googleMap.clear();

            // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
            for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {

                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                LatLng latLng;
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),
                        address.getLongitude());

                String addressText = String.format(
                        "%s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                                .getAddressLine(0) : "", address
                                .getCountryName());
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                // markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(addressText);

                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // Locate the first location
                if (i == 0)
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }







}
```

***Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mamun.tasktest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-library  android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCgGng3iaqbTxJ3B_lYemZBEqXOonUtFEI" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
       <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

       </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LogCat**

```
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mamun.tasktest/com.mamun.tasktest.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mamun.tasktest.MapsActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mamun.tasktest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mamun.tasktest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mamun.tasktest.MapsActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mamun.tasktest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mamun.tasktest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
02-28 16:52:05.369: E/AndroidRuntime(11464):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: The [MapsActivity api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity) says the `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` should be a child of *application*, not a child of *manifest*, as you have here... does that help?

Comment: I can't understand clearly what u r saying.Can u give me anexample or modify my code plz..@ Menno

Comment: Move `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` from where it is now, to the line before `<activity android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.MainActivity"`

Comment: No. That's not valid XML. `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/><activity android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" > </activity>`

Comment: It is working now @Menno

Comment: It's not crashing now.But I do not get the lat & lon when I touch .though I used onTouchEvent method inside the inner class MapOverlay . I need it most to get lat & lon when I touch .Can u help me plz..@Menno

Comment: This isn't a chat :-) But it seems like you're using an old Maps API anyway, try using this one: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/